# Designing a generic Rest API

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to design a rest api server in django. I am confused how to name the rest api

I have stored data in form of a matrix and 'rest api' allows various data transformations

eg
1. Apply mathematical function on a row
2. Apply mathematical function on a column
3. Remove row
4. Remove column
5. Add row
6. Add Column
7. Remove row if values are missing
---- so on

Can someone suggest me the right way of naming the rest apis. Should I go for one rest api for each one?. If yes, how will the url look like for GET/POST/DELETE/PUT ?

It will be helpful if you can point out an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For,

1. Apply mathematical function on a row
2. Apply mathematical function on a column

These above should take the URL form of `/api/v1/(?P<type>(row|column))/(?P<id>\d+)/math_function/(?P<math_function_name>\w+)$`
These should also only respect 'PUT or PATCH' since, if we are following RESTful design, we are only looking to update a row or column with data from a mathematical function.  The math_function is technically a sub collection of row or columns, hence why it's last in the URL structure.

---

For,

3. Remove row
4. Remove column
5. Add row
6. Add Column

These above should take the URL form of `/api/v1/(?P<type>(row|column))/(?P<id>\d+)/$`
These should also only respect 'POST or DELETE' as the only actions according to business logic says to remove or add.

---

For,

7. Remove row if values are missing

This should take the URL form of `/api/v1/(?P<type>(row|column))/(?P<id>\d+)/conditional/(?P<condition_name>\w+)/$`
The above endpoint should only respect 'DELETE' as we will only be removing rows here.

---

The above was written with the RESTful API design of `/api/version/collection/id/subcollection/subid/`

Comment: Does the mathematical function recommended to add it in the url ?. I thought , it has to be sent as part of parameters.

Comment: /api/v1/(?P<type>(row|column))/(?P<id>\d+)/math_function/(?P<math_function_name>\w+)$  'math_function_name' is capturing the name of the mathematical function you would like to run, it's going to require some logic in your view to handle each math_function_name

Comment: yeah. that is true. But, if I have 20 mathematical functions, isn't better to send the mathematical function in parameter list

Comment: So there would be a use case in which you need to run N number of mathematical functions at a given time?